# Get spanned text in EditText

Tags: android

I want to know if there is any style applied to a selected text in EditText. For example

"This is BOLD"

Here is want I want to achieve, If selected is bold then remove bold else apply bold

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use the `getEditableText()` method on the EditText view to get an Editable - which has a method `getFilters()`. you should be able to loop through the filters to see if the selected area is covered by one of them.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html

Comment: Rather than `getFilters()`, `getSpans()` can report whether there is a span of any given type in a particular range.

Comment: that's a better way to do it.

Comment: how can i get the text in a particular range? In string i am able to do this by substring method